# Problems with Qt checkbox slot

Tags: qt

I am trying to design a dialogue where you click the corresponding checkbox(underline, bold, italic) and then the words in textedit will automatically change to underline, bold or italic.

I've inserted three slots linked to three checkboxes. However, only the Underline checkbox works!The other two checkboxes do not work at all! Nothing happens when I check them.

Below are the codes I write. Is there any mistake? Why would things like this happen T_T

Please help me.
Thank you!

```
void Dialog::on_checkBoxUnder_clicked(bool checked)
{
    QFont font = ui->textEdit->font();
    font.setUnderline(checked);
    ui->textEdit->setFont(font);

}

void Dialog::on_checkBoxItalic_clicked(bool checked)
{
    QFont font = ui->textEdit->font();
    font.setItalic(checked);
    ui->textEdit->setFont(font);
}

void Dialog::on_checkBoxBold_clicked(bool checked)
{
    QFont font = ui-> textEdit->font();
    font.setBold(checked);
    ui->textEdit->setFont(font);
}
```

Comment: if you want help provide a [mcve], on the other hand have you checked if the other slots are called?

Comment: Did you link the slots to the signals?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How do I link the slots to the signals? In the Signal and Slots Editor or? But the problem is, the first slot works perfectly fine but the other two do not run><

Comment: Make sure your checkboxes are named exactly `checkBoxUnder`, `checkBoxItalic` and `checkBoxBold`. If the the UI is done with UI Designer it should call `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` in the generated code what auto-connects widgets' signals by object name.

Answer (score 0):

Try stateChanged instead. This example works:

```
void MainWindow::on_cbItalic_stateChanged(int arg1)
{
    QFont font = ui->textEdit->font();
    font.setItalic(arg1);
    ui->textEdit->setFont(font);
}

void MainWindow::on_cbBold_stateChanged(int arg1)
{
    QFont font = ui->textEdit->font();
    font.setBold(arg1);
    ui->textEdit->setFont(font);
}
```